# Missing values in Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, missing-data, sparklyr

I am trying to count the missing values of a particular coulmn in the DataFrame in Sparklyr like below

```
 count(filter(subdata, isNull(subdata$metric)))
Source:   query [1 x 1]
Database: spark connection master=local[4] app=sparklyr local=TRUE

       n
   <dbl>
1 216360``
```

But the result returned is the total number of rows in the dataframe. Am I missing something. Kindly Point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will count the number of `NA` values for a given column using `sparklyr`:

```
  count_na_values <- function(column) {
    # Count NA Values for a given column using sparklyr.
    #
    # Args:
    #   column: (char) name of column.
    na_count <- df %>%
      filter(is.na(rlang::sym(column))) %>%
      sdf_nrow()
    na_count
  }
```

Note - `df` should be of class `"tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"`; e.g.

`df <- tbl(sc, <table>)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mixing `SparkR` (`isNull`) and `sparklyr` (the rest) APIs. As far as I am aware this is not supported and at the first glance it looks your code should actually throw an exception.

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(1, NA), y=c(-1, 2))
copy_to(sc, df, "df", overwrite=TRUE) %>% filter(is.na(x)) %>% count()
```

```
Source:   query [1 x 1]
Database: spark connection ...
      n
  <dbl>
1     1
```